# How to send e-mail to users within a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, sendmail

I want to send an e-mail to users within a database.

**SQL query:**

`SELECT nickname, email FROM db_Users;`

I want the e-mail to use both columns for example:

To: %email

Hi %nickname,

Message

Can someone show me basic example to do it using a shell script? I just want the basics to know how to get started and not a fully written script :-)

Thanks

Comment: are you using powershell or vb script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I use parameter for replace variables like that. Something like this :

--top of script

```
NAME=$(mysql -u $USER $DBNAME -p$PWD -sN -e "SELECT nickname FROM db_Users")
EMAIL=$(mysql -u $USER $DBNAME -p$PWD -sN -e "SELECT email FROM db_Users")

echo "${NAME} Message for you" | mail -s "This is the subject" ${EMAIL}
```

You could do a loop fot each user, including all members in list :

```
I=0
for i in ${NAME[@]}
do
    -- E-mail 
    I=`expr $I + 1`
done
```